# Prove that $f(x)=x^n$ is differentiable at every real $x$ and calculate its derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

In order to prove that f is differentiable at a point we can
consider if the limit (of the basic differentiation expression) exists.

However how can I prove that this function is differentiable at every real x?

[image]

Comment: Write a difference quotient and use the binomial theorem. Showing its differentiable at an arbitrary point is exactly showing it is differentiable at every real.

Comment: Recall that $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+b^{n-1})$. Let $a=x+h$ and $b=x$. Now use the above factorization to simplify $\frac{(x+h)^n -x^n}{h}$.

Answer (score 2):

A more instructive proof, I think, uses induction and the product rule.

> **Lemma**: If $f,g$ are differentiable functions on some open set $U\subset \mathbb R$, then $fg$ is differentiable, and $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$.

For if $x_0\in U$, then
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x_0)}{x-x_0} &= \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x_0)+f(x)g(x_0)-f(x_0)g(x_0)}{x-x_0} \\
&=\frac{f(x)(g(x)-g(x_0)) + g(x_0)(f(x)-f(x_0))}{x-x_0}\\
&= f(x)\left(\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0} \right) + g(x_0)\left(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \right)\\
&\stackrel{x\to x_0}\longrightarrow f(x_0)g'(x_0) + g(x_0)f'(x_0).
\end{align}

> **Theorem** If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is given by $f(x)=x^n$, for $n\geqslant 1$, then $f$ is differentiable and $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$.

For $n=1$ we have for any $x\ne x_0$
$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \frac{x-x_0}{x-x_0} = 1,$$
so $f(x)=x$ has derivative $f'(x)=1 = nx^{n-1}$. Assuming that $f(x)=x^n$ has derivative $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ for some $n\geqslant 0$, then $$g(x)=x^{n+1}=f(x)h(x)$$
where $h(x)=x$ and
\begin{align}
g'(x) &= f'(x)h(x) + f(x)h'(x)\\
&= nx^{n-1}x + x^n\cdot1\\
&= (n+1)x^n,
\end{align}
from which we conclude.